# How do I show related articles for knowledge articles (not via Smartlink)?

Tags: related-list, knowledge, articles

I am trying to display related articles for knowledge articles.

e.g. Customer opens an article about Dogs. Links to articles about Dog nutrition and dog leashes are automatically displayed.

Is there a way to do so in a more intuitive, automated manner as opposed to SmartLink-ing between articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using customer service template and communities these features are already provided by the platform .

Here is the document showing the related article [component](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_related_articles.htm&type=0)

If you are on classic community then you will need to build your own .

Comment: thanks for your response! If I'm trying to access it through the Knowledge/Articles tab, will I also need to build my own?

Comment: Yes. You will have to build your own if you need related articles

Comment: Alright thanks for the tip! If it's not too much to ask for, could you point me to somewhere where I can learn to build my own component? Cos I'm pretty new to Salesforce and I do not know where to start. Sorry and thanks in advance!!

Comment: Trailhead might be your best bet .Look for Salesforce trailhead online and you will see great content around visualforce page. You will need to write an apex and controller and inline vf to achieve this functionality

Comment: Does anyone know how articles are deemed to be related? I cannot see anything in Salesforce's documentation to explain it.